# ASP.NET jQuery: how to remove div element outside another div element when dropdown has changed?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, canvas

this is my div structures

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 90%;" class="goleft">
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
                    <p>
                        <select name="DropDownList3" id="DropDownList3" class="form-control show-tick">
                            <option value="--Pilih Periode--">--Pilih Periode--</option>
                            <option value="Juni, 2017">Juni, 2017</option>
                            <option value="Juli, 2017">Juli, 2017</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">
                    <a id="LinkButton3" class="btn btn-primary btn-link-2 btn-block btReload-3 has-spinners" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkButton3&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Muat Ulang</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bar_chart_container">
        <p>Chart total</p>
        <canvas id="bar_chart" height="250" class="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

when the `id="DropDownList3"` 
has changed then, i want to remove the canvas with ID `id="bar_chart"` inside the div with ID `id="bar_chart_container"` located at the last of div that not group in the `<div class="row-fluid">`, and appending the new canvas with same ID. how its done with jQuery?

here i was going so far but didn't work perfectly as expected

`var cvs = $('#bar_chart').find(':last-child').not(':only-child').remove();
$('#bar_chart').remove();
$('#bar_chart_container').append('<canvas id="bar_chart" height="250" class="chart"><canvas>');
var ctx = $("#bar_chart").get(0).getContext('2d');`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to remove the element and then re-create the same element, as you'll just be back in the same place as when you started.

Assuming all you want to do is simply hide the canvas on changing the dropdown, all you have to do is attach an `onchange` event handler to the `<select>` box, and then tie this in to a function that hides the desired element. Here, I'm creating a funciton called `dropdownChange()`, and calling `onchange="dropdownChange()"`. I've added a slight border to the canvas to aid in clarity.

```js
function dropdownChange() {
  document.getElementById('bar_chart').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#bar_chart {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 90%;" class="goleft">
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
        <p>
          <select name="DropDownList3" id="DropDownList3" class="form-control show-tick" onchange="dropdownChange()">
            <option value="--Pilih Periode--">--Pilih Periode--</option>
            <option value="Juni, 2017">Juni, 2017</option>
            <option value="Juli, 2017">Juli, 2017</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">
        <a id="LinkButton3" class="btn btn-primary btn-link-2 btn-block btReload-3 has-spinners" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkButton3&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Muat Ulang</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bar_chart_container">
  <p>Chart total</p>
  <canvas id="bar_chart" height="250" class="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

To actually remove the element and re-create it, you can use `document.createElement("canvas");` to create a brand new element, and then `$('#bar_chart_container').append();` to insert the newly-created canvas as follows:

```js
function dropdownChange() {
  document.getElementById('bar_chart').style.display = 'none';
  var new_canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // Create a <div> node
  new_canvas.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
  $('#bar_chart_container').append(new_canvas);
}
```

```css
#bar_chart {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 90%;" class="goleft">
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
        <p>
          <select name="DropDownList3" id="DropDownList3" class="form-control show-tick" onchange="dropdownChange()">
            <option value="--Pilih Periode--">--Pilih Periode--</option>
            <option value="Juni, 2017">Juni, 2017</option>
            <option value="Juli, 2017">Juli, 2017</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">
        <a id="LinkButton3" class="btn btn-primary btn-link-2 btn-block btReload-3 has-spinners" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkButton3&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Muat Ulang</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bar_chart_container">
  <p>Chart total</p>
  <canvas id="bar_chart" height="250" class="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for the comment, i appreciate it that you help, but hiding the canvas didn't works for my issue. if i choose twice or more of the option change, then it's not clear the series that i have been choose before.

Comment: I've added a second example that clearly shows the deletion and creation of a new canvas, by changing its border colour.

Comment: i've tried but the canvas just showing the border, i'm loosing of my data and series. and, if i changed the option more than once, the canvas is appending more too